# Why is my game delay happening before I want it to?

Tags: python, pygame, delay, pause

I'm creating a game in pygame and I wanted to display "Level Complete" text at the end of the level. I wanted to create a delay after the text is blitted so it will be displayed for a few seconds. However, the delay keeps occurring before my text is displayed, despite the line of code being after the text is blitted. Here is the link to my game:

[Swamp_Game](https://repl.it/@p_loo/Full-SwampGame-Ask)

I tried using the `pygame.time.delay()` function, but it kept making the pause happen before my text.

```py
# lines 101-107 on main.py

screen.blit(field, field_rect)
core_text(screen, "Level Complete!", 100, 150, 200, BLACK)
pygame.time.delay(2000)
screen.blit(swamp, swamp_rect)
level_2() # function to initiate level 2
clock.tick(20)
pygame.display.flip()
```

I wanted the pause to occur after the text is shown, but it keeps happening before it. As a result, my text is only displayed for a fraction of a second before it moves onto the next level and is barely visible.

Answer (score 1):

> but it kept making the pause happen before my text.

The text is drawn before delay, but it is not visible on the display.

Of course, you've to update the display by either [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) or [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update), before [`pygame.time.delay()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.delay).
Further you should handle the events (e.g. [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump)) - some systems need event handling for display update.

```py
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.event.pump()
pygame.time.delay(2000)
pygame.event.pump()
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you show me where this would go in my code? I tried adding pygame.display.flip() and pygame.event.pump() before where pygame.time.delay(2000) currently is, but the result hasn't changed.

Comment: @the_coder `core_text` `.blit` the text on `screen`, isn't it? Try to put a 2nd `pygame.event.pump()` after `pygame.time.delay`